How to register a bean when it is not already register in a BeanDefinitionPostProcessor
Let's say there is an interface SpecialInterface, I have a BeanDefinitionPostProcessor implementation:
public class MyBeanDefPostProcessor 
         implements BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor {

   @Override
   public void postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(
      BeanDefinitionRegistry registry ) throws BeansException {
      
      if ( !this.isAlreadyRegistered(SpecialInterface.class, registry) ) {
          // If it is not there, I want to register one
          var beanDef = new RootBeanDefition();
          // the rest of the values on beadDef
          registry.registerBeanDefinition("SomeName", beanDef );
      }
   }

   protected boolean isAlreadyRegistered(
          Class<?> clazz, 
          BeanDefinitionRegistry registry ) {
     // How do I know if there is a bean already registered 
     // implementing that interface
   }
}

The information is there but not in the BeanDefinition interface.
Any ideas will be beneficial!

Maybe method containsBeanDefinition from BeanDefinitionRegistry is what you're looking for.
Take a look over the documentation: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/support/BeanDefinitionRegistry.html#containsBeanDefinition(java.lang.String).
You could specify the name of the bean and simply check if it returns false.
Example:
protected boolean isAlreadyRegistered(
          Class<?> clazz, 
          BeanDefinitionRegistry registry ) {
        return registry.containsBeanDefinition(clazz.getName());
}

P.S. there's a missing not (!) statement in your if.

Thank you very much for your answer. The .containsBeanDefinition(String beanName) bean name is not necessarily the bean class name. For example, if the bean is created with BeanClass getBeanClass(), the bean name will be getBeanClass. Thank you also for the correction of the code ;-)
